# PJAX after AJAX template rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, pjax

I have an application that uses jQuery and pjax (standalone). We're trying to experiment to see if we can use the possibly more flexible and smaller npm pjax over jquery-pjax.

One of my functions sets the html of a div after loading data, and this html includes links that we want as pjax links, for example `$('#link-container').html('<a href="/account_detail.html?='+account.id+'" data-pjax >')`. However clicking on this link causes a full page reload rather than a pjax request.

Is there a way to reimplement pjax? When I try `new PJAX({elements:[a[data-pjax]]})` inside the pjax:success call (whenDOMReady from the project page - https://www.npmjs.org/package/pjax) it uses pjax... but then loads resources twice.

Perhaps the best solution is going with jquery-pjax ($(document).pjax(a[data-pjax] etc.) but I wanted to see if anyone has come across this type of issue before. Perhaps it is rare to include jQuery and non-jQuery pjax, but it seems like this can happen for any asynchronous data query and DOM modification, and I just want to re-PJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using jquery-pjax, and when you use it or configure it wrong - it also refresh the page, so you're experiencing one of the issues I've encountered.

In any way, I'm not sure if it will help your problem or not, but I suggest everyone to use Firefox with Firebug and in the "Console" tab to click on "Persist" you usually find some errors there that might be helpful, and since errors somewhere might cause the page to refresh - sometime you miss it as the console is being refreshed too.

What I learned is that you need to make sure that when you write:

```
<a href="/account_detail.html?=2" data-pjax>bla</a>
```

You need to have a container - that PJAX drops the content into, like:

```
<div id="pjax-container"></div>
```

And initially you configure PJAX to bind these objects:

```
<script>
  // this is how I define it in jquery-pjax, so adjust it as you use it.
  $(document).pjax('a[data-pjax]', '#pjax-container');
</script>
```

so the key points that I learned that causes refresh with PJAX:

- I'm sending a header twice ( back-end code )
- The container was suddenly removed from the HTML body ( the div id="pjax-container" ) and when the DOM is missing it doesn't have a
  place to drop the HTML - so it just refresh the page.
- When I initially bind the a[data-pjax] with jQuery, new DOM object are not automatically re-bind by jQuery ( unless using "live/on"), therefor they act as a regular `<a>` tag and reload the page with the new URL.
- some JS/PJAX syntax error

In your case, if the pjax-container is "#link-container" I'm not sure if it's a good idea to place the  tags inside it.